# How to retrieve specific session data from database in codeigniter 3?

Tags: database, session, codeigniter-3

I am having problem on retrieving data from database in codeigniter 3. First of all, my session database is working (it is storing the session as i want) but the problem is that in codeigniter 3, the data that you've set in the session will be stored as blob data type [according here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#session-drivers)

What i want to do is to have authorization from viewing the pages of my website (ex. an employee cannot view the admin page) and also to prevent the same user logging in at the same time. Any suggestion? :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you shouldn't be trying to access session data in that fashion. You should be setting session variables like this (for example setting login data):

```
$logindata = array(
    'id' => $id,
    'email' => $email
);
$this->session->set_userdata($logindata);
```

Then you should be retrieving it like this:

```
$id = $this->session->userdata('id');
```

What you do with it at that point is up to you. For example, you could do something like this:

```
if (!$id) {
    redirect(base_url() . 'login');
} else {
    //do your stuff here for valid logged in users
}
```

Obviously you can store and retrieve whatever you like. So you can store a users role or permission or whatever else you define.